# Convergence of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdy \frac{\vert xy\vert^{p}}{\vert x-y\vert^q}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Does the following integral converges

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dxdy \frac{\vert xy\vert^{p}}{\vert x-y\vert^q} \;?$$

With $p>1$ and $0<q<1$, I tried looking for exemple at $p=2$ and $q=1/2$ but no result so far.

I used Wolfram and no answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\vert xy\vert^{p}}{\vert x-y\vert^q} dxdy= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\vert xy\vert^{p}}{\vert x-y\vert^q}dxdy$$ $$\geq  \int_{\{|x|<1\}}\int_{\{|y|>1\}}\frac{\vert xy\vert^{p}}{\vert x-y\vert^q}dxdy$$ $$\geq \int_{\{|x|<1\}}\int_{\{|y|>1\}}\frac{|x|^p }{( 1+|y|)^q}dxdy$$  $$= \int_{\{|x|<1\}}|x|^pdx\int_{\{|y|>1\}}\frac{ 1}{( 1+|y|)^q}dy$$ $$\geq\int_{\{|x|<1\}}|x|^pdx\int_{\{|y|>1\}}\frac{ 1}{( 1+|y|)}dy=+\infty$$

Comment: I don't understand your second inequality, can you explain ?

Comment: When $|x|<1 $ then $|x-y| \leq |y|+1$ ,thus $\frac{1}{|x-y|} \geq \frac{1}{1+|y|}$